# Wpf app taskbar icon not showing when launched from scheduled task at login in W10

Tags: wpf, windows-task-scheduler

I have a wpf app with the main form hidden, only a taskbar icon to interact with.
It works fine, i mean, exe double-click icon appears, interact, close...
On Windows 7 also works without any issue.

Here the weird thing... If i create a scheduled task to launch it on user login, it works only in W7, in Windows 10 the icon is hidden.

I know that the app is running and doing stuff because of the implemented log.

By the way, i'm using Harcodet taskbar declared in xaml this way:

```
<tb:TaskbarIcon x:Name="TBIcon"
    IconSource="{Binding ViewModel.Status, Converter={StaticResource TaskBarIconConverter}}"
    ToolTipText="{Binding ViewModel.TbIconToolTip, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
...
```

Windows version is 10.0.16299.64

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the scheduled task option to "Run only when user is logged on" (for W7 and W10) in the general tab of the task:

[image]